# Language Learning feedback with AI

Tags: ai-design, activation-functions, data-preprocessing, text-classification, knowledge-base

Is there a program under development that uses AI technology, like Siri, to "hold hands" so to speak with a language learner and coach them on accent, colloqiual expressions, or to let them guide the language learning process using an archive of language knowledge? 
Also, could this sort of program be used to learn things in a language one already knows, or in a new language, say for the purposes of travel or to learn about related hyperlinks in an online database?